# objective-c - calling one constructor from another

Tags: objective-c

Say you had the following two constructors:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title page:(NSString *)page;
```

The second constructor is no different from the first, except that it sets up the member variable "page".

Since it basically has to do the same thing, is there a way to call the first one from the second one to reduce code duplication, or do you have to set up a third method to do the common tasks?

I'm talking about something similar to this, though I doubt this will work:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)_title {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self.title = _title;
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)_title page:(NSString *)_page {
     if(self = [self initWithTitle:_title]) {
         self.page = _page;
     }

     return self;
}
```

Comment: @phunehehe has a better solution, but what you posted *will* work.

Comment: Huh, I guess it will, now that I think about it.  Thanks

Comment: The sooner you drop the C++ terms and start using the Objective-C terms, the sooner the documentation is going to start making sense.  Objective-C doesn't have constructors or member variables.  It has initializers and instance variables.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are saying is weird because I'm thinking of this

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)_title {
    return [self initWithTitle:_title page:nil];
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)_title page:(NSString *)_page {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self.title = _title;
        self.page = _page;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 23):

First, you don't have constructors, you have two initializers:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title page:(NSString *)page;
```

As with most initializers, the goal is to setup some instance variables (not member variables).

The first step is to identify your designated initializer.  In your case, it could be:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title page:(NSString *)page;
```

Which means that `- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;` would be implemented as others have described:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)_title {
    return [self initWithTitle:_title page:nil];
}
```

However, I would recommend against this pattern as it makes subclassing more error prone than it should be.  In subclassing, you must always override the designated initializer *or* you must implement a new initializer that calls the designated initializer.  Obviously, the more initializers you have, the more potential for bugs in subclassing you might introduce.

Furthermore, this:

```
Foo *f = [[Foo alloc] initWithTitle: @"Foo!" page: nil];
```

Is far more clear than this:

```
Foo *f = [[Foo alloc] initWithTitle: @"Foo!"];
```

The first indicates quite specifically that you have thought about `page` and decided to explicitly set it to `nil` or otherwise rely on the class `Foo` to set the page reasonably.  The second gives no such indication.

Both subclassing and explicit indication of intention are the primary reasons why you will find a lack of such convenience methods across Cocoa (there are some, but most are quite old -- older than when the policy really became rule).

Comment: You can't avoid the pattern when you are creating a category that introduces a new initializer and you simply want to call an existing initializer.